# Android > Unknown Host Errors while installing ADT plugin in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am trying to setup development environment for Android development. While adding Android ADT plugin in eclipse, I get following error:

> Fetching
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml Failed
>   to fetch URL
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml,
>   reason: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com Fetched Add-ons List
>   successfully Fetching URL:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml Failed
>   to fetch URL
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml, reason:
>   dl-ssl.google.com Done loading packages.

Could someone guide me easily that how to get rid of this error?

Comment: The "Unknown Host" error message sounds like a DNS or internet connection problem, but it could also be server side issues. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010375/android-sdk-installation-issue-peer-not-authenticated/9026997

Comment: No, not a duplicate of that - this is a DNS failure, that is an authentication failure.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
In the **Tools>Options** menu in **Android SDK Manager**, I set the `HTTP Proxy Server` and `HTTP Proxy Port` values (I used the same settings that for my internet browser).
That fixed the problem for me !

Answer (score 3):

In the **Tools>Options** menu check the option

> Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://

Comment: No, I mean in the SDK Manager.

Comment: Ubuntu's Android SDK manager does not have the Tools component.

Comment: I'm not sure if it did earlier, but it does now.

Answer (score 2):

You may be having the problem cause you are on a network where Proxy server and proxy ports are used for intercommunication between devices. Set the appropriate proxy server and port number in `Tools -> Options`. If its still not working then go for
Force `https://...` sources to be fetched using `http://`

Answer (score 0):

Try manually downloading the platform from here: http://sochinda.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-install-android-sdk-offline-not-completely-offline/

Choose the version you want, download and extract into platform-tools!

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same error:

> Unknown Host Errors while installing ADT plugin in eclipse

Go to Setting -> Default setting -> select "Android SDK" from left side Panel.
Select required components Which you want to install. - >Apply -> Ok.