# How can I download older Android versions in Android Studio? I want to make the emulator run KitKat but it shows only Lollipop

Tags: android, sdk

I want Android Studio Emulator to run a previous Android version to test web pages. How can I download or make changes in the Android Studio to make the Emulator run 4.4 and not Lollipop?

Comment: As a suggestion (I know it isn't an answer to your question) you might want to look into alternate emulators such as Genymotion as the native emulator isn't known for being fantastic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 1:** Install KitKal 4.4 SDK Platform from SDK Manager

[image]

**Step 2:** Open **AVD Manager** (Create or Edit emulator)

[image]

**Step 3:** Change API level

[image]

Comment: I don't see an option to install Android 4.4

Comment: API 19 is 4.4.2 (which is 4.4 with bug fixes)

Comment: You can  create emulator by API level not by OS version

Comment: Looks like I don't see them because of this error when I open the SDK Manager: **Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: peer not authenticated**
Any workaround to fix this?

Comment: Nevermind.. I had to disconnect form my company's network. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010375/android-sdk-installation-issue-peer-not-authenticated

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to download the SDK version you wish to run your application on trough the SDK manager.

Assuming you have already done that you simply need to create your own new virtual device trough the AVD manager.

[image: You can do that here]

From there on out it's very clear what you have to do.

If you still have problems you can consult:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

Answer (score -1):

Look at the following screenshot:

[image: Android Studio]

The third icon is the SDK Manager where you can download the system images to build AVD, the fourth icon is where you can create new AVD.

Personally i recommend you to download [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/store) which uses VirtualBox to run Android virtual device and it's very much faster than the standard emulator.

Answer (score -1):

You can open SDK Manager From

and select API leve from list

click Install XX packages button,

hope can help you