# How to “Force fetch using http://" in Android SDK from command line

Tags: android, linux, android-sdk-tools

I have exactly this problem:

[Android SDK installation issue - Peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010375/android-sdk-installation-issue-peer-not-authenticated)

> I am trying to install the Android SDK and I get the following error
>   in the SDK Manager Logs -
>
> ```
> Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
> Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml,
> reason: peer not authenticated
> Fetched Add-ons List successfully
> Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml
> Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-5.xml, reason:
> peer not authenticated
> Done loading packages.
> ```

I'm not behind a proxy and all the responses I've found  there, and in other similar questions, are:

> enable the "Force https://... sources to be fetched using
>   http://..." setting in the SDK Manager Tools > Options menu.

But I'm on a CentOS 6 installation without GUI (it's a continuous integration server).

How can I force or set this configuration when running from command line?

Edit: I've also checked that the files can be downloaded with wget:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
```

Comment: Don't know for sure, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20240708/2096401) may help (top search result for _set "Force https://" android sdk_)

Comment: I've also tried it but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could not be easier, I don't know how I missed it (－‸ლ) :

```
./android list sdk --no-ui --no-https
```

The `--no-https` option does the trick. It is described in the help section of the action:

```
$ ./android --help list sdk

       Usage:
       android [global options] list sdk [action options]
       Global options:
  -h --help       : Help on a specific command.
  -v --verbose    : Verbose mode, shows errors, warnings and all messages.
     --clear-cache: Clear the SDK Manager repository manifest cache.
  -s --silent     : Silent mode, shows errors only.

                   Action "list sdk":
  Lists remote SDK repository.
Options:
  -o --obsolete  : Deprecated. Please use --all instead.
  -a --all       : Lists all available packages (including obsolete and
                   installed ones)
     --proxy-host: HTTP/HTTPS proxy host (overrides settings if defined)
     --proxy-port: HTTP/HTTPS proxy port (overrides settings if defined)
  -s --no-https  : Uses HTTP instead of HTTPS (the default) for downloads.
  -e --extended  : Displays extended details on each package
  -u --no-ui     : Displays list result on console (no GUI) [Default: true]
```