# can not download android API

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm using Eclipse in Windows 7 x86.
I can not download any api for my SDK manager.
It can download some of files like SDK platform, samples & etc but for others it gives this error (in the image).

What should I do?

[image: error for api22]

Comment: You should search for the errors you get. Google something like 'android sdk peer not authenticated'. The first result gave me this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010375/android-sdk-installation-issue-peer-not-authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running it on windows, open android studio or SDK manager with admin privilege.->  `Run As Administrator`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it again but this time as Admin, that should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

i run it as admin then i download & install packages sporadik